# Uncountable collection of open sets.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Can there be an uncountable collection of open sets in $\Bbb R^n$?

My idea: Since every open set contains at least one rational number, I can match each open sets to rational numbers and rational numbers are countable. Thus collection of open sets must be countable.

My professor said "the union of an arbitrary collection of open subsets of $M$ is open, and arbitrary mean either finite, countably infinite or uncountably infinite".
Here $M$ is a metric space.

Comment: The issue with your explanation is that there is no guarantee there is a unique rational for each open set.

Comment: @DonThousand Do you mean each open sets should have one rational numbers or there must be no two open sets that have same rational numbers? Sorry im not good at english

Comment: If you want just an uncountable collection of open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$, consider this set $\mathscr{F} = \left\lbrace B_1 \left( x \right) | x \in \mathbb{R}^n \right\rbrace$, where $B_1 \left( x \right) = \left\lbrace y \in \mathbb{R}^n | d \left( x, y \right) < 1 \right\rbrace$ is the open ball of radius $1$ centered at $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. This is an uncountable collection of open sets.

Comment: You have proved indeed that there is no uncountable collection of **pairwise disjoint** open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: If you add in the requirement that the sets be pairwise disjoint, then no: $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a Lindelof space, precisely for reasons you articulated. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindelöf_space. There do however exist metric spaces that can have an uncountable connection of pairwise disjoint open sets; for example, $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the discrete metric.